# SVG - маска с фильтром feGaussianBlur радиальным градиентом

Tags: html, svg, blur, svg-filter

Я хочу размыть углы изображения, сохранив резкий центр. Использование css `backdrop-blur()` исключено, потому что Firefox его не поддерживает. Добавление резкого изображения поверх размытого и затем маскирование первого также неосуществимо, так как в конце я хочу изменить статическое изображение с помощью сцены three.js.

Я попытался следовать [этому руководству](https://www.sitepoint.com/design-tricks-with-svg-filters-a-masked-blur-effect/), но с радиальным градиентом, а не с фиксированной полосой.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        <filter id="blurlayer" width="100%" height="100%">
            
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" result="blur"/>
            
          <radialGradient id="radialGradient" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%" result="mask">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" />
          </radialGradient>
            
          <feComposite in="blur" in2="mask" operator="in" result="comp" />
            
          <feMerge result="merge">
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
            <feMergeNode in="comp" />
          </feMerge> 
        </filter>
      </defs>

      <image filter="url(#blurlayer)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"   xlink:href="https://www.wildtextures.com/wp-content/uploads/wildtextures-grey-felt-texture.jpg"/>
    </svg>
```

Это не работает. Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне узнать почему?
Я разместил [codepen](https://codepen.io/morph3us-net/pen/GRvYENX?editors=1100), если это кому-то поможет.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG - mask feGaussianBlur with radialGradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69967936/7394871) от участника  [@morph3us](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11601227/morph3us).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69967936/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно проделать немного больше работы - вы не можете поместить `radialGradient` в середину фильтра - внутри фильтра разрешены только примитивы фильтра, и вам нужно импортировать любое изображение / фигуру, которую вы хотите использовать, через `feImage`.

Кроме того, при маскировании с помощью `feComposite / in` - оператор «in» использует только альфа-канал (в отличие от реальных масок, использующих яркость), поэтому вы можете использовать черный / черный градиент с переменной непрозрачностью.

Наконец, поскольку Firefox не поддерживает идентификаторы фрагментов внутри `feImage`, поэтому если вам нужна поддержка Firefox, вы должны определить свою маску в содержимом и импортировать изображение, которое вы хотите использовать, через `feImage`.
Это делает фильтр не пригодным для повторного использования, но если это один раз, это нормально.
Если вы действительно хотите использовать этот фильтр в более общем плане, вы можете определить прямоугольник с градиентной заливкой, а затем преобразовать его в полное изображение SVG, которое вы затем встроите через `data: uri внутри feImage`.
Это больше работы (и мне всегда кажется, что правила экранирования для `svg + xml data URI` неверны), поэтому я не делал этого здесь.

**FWIW** - это руководство полное и правильное.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
        
        <radialGradient id="radialGradient" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%" result="mask">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="1" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" />
        </radialGradient>
            
        
        <filter id="blurlayer" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
          <feImage xlink:href="https://www.wildtextures.com/wp-content/uploads/wildtextures-grey-felt-texture.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" result="original-image" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>         
          <feComposite in="original-image" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="unblurred" />  
          
     <feGaussianBlur in="original-image" stdDeviation="4" result="blurred-image"/>
          <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="invertlight">
                <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
          </feComponentTransfer>
          <feComposite in="blurred-image" operator="in"/>
          
          <feComposite operator="over" in="unblurred"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
  
<g filter="url(#blurlayer)">
      <rect fill="url(#radialGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</g>
    </svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Примечание переводчика:*

**FWIW** одна из самых вежливых текстовых аббревиатур, которая расшифровывается, как «не знаю, насколько это важно

Речь идёт о ссылке на [руководство](https://www.sitepoint.com/design-tricks-with-svg-filters-a-masked-blur-effect/), указанной в вопросе

### Update

Вот как будет выглядеть версия data: uri: (обратите внимание, что мне пришлось немного увеличить размер отфильтрованного содержимого, чтобы фильтр обрезал краевые артефакты, вызываемые инверсией).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
      <defs>        
        <filter id="blurlayer" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
          <feImage xlink:href='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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' width="100%" height="100%" result="blur-mask" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
      <feComposite in2="blur-mask" in="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="unblurred" /> 
     <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blurred-image"/>
          <feComponentTransfer in="blur-mask" result="invertlight">
             <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
          </feComponentTransfer>
          <feComposite in="blurred-image" operator="in"/>
          <feComposite operator="over" in="unblurred"/>
      </filter>
</defs>
  
  <g filter="url(#blurlayer)">
      <image xlink:href="https://www.wildtextures.com/wp-content/uploads/wildtextures-grey-felt-texture.jpg" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%" preserveAspectRatio="none"/> 
</g>
    </svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод  [Ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973885/7394871) от участника  [@Michael Mullany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271353/michael-mullany).</sub>

***Данные: uri - это версия SVG в кодировке base64.***

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100%" width="100%"><defs><radialGradient id="myGradient" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%" result="mask"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="1" /><stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0"/>
</radialGradient></defs><rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#myGradient)"/></svg>
```